# Locus of centers of circles tangent to a given line and a given circle

Tags: geometry

> I'm trying to find locus of centers of circles tangent to $y$ axis and tangent to the unit circle ($x^2 + y^2 = 1$).

#### My try:

Call $(x,y)$ the center of the circle. We know 
$$d( (x,y), y\text{-axis}) = |x| $$

Pick point $(a,b)$ on the unit circle. Then 
$$\begin{align}
d( (a,b), (x,y) ) 
&= \sqrt{ (a-x)^2 + (b-y)^2 } \\[4pt]
&= \sqrt{ a^2 - 2ax + x^2 + b^2 - 2by + y^2 } \\[4pt]
&= \sqrt{ x^2+y^2 - 2ax-2by + 1 }
\end{align}$$

We have that $d( (x,y), \text{y-axis}) = d( (a,b), (x,y) ) $ so

$$\begin{align}
|x| &= \sqrt{x^2+y^2 - 2ax-2by + 1} \\[4pt]
\implies \qquad\qquad\quad x^2 &= x^2 + y^2 - 2ax-2by+1 \\[4pt]
\implies \qquad 2ax+2by &=y^2 + 1
\end{align}$$

My question is:

> What should I do with $a,b$? I mean, they are not constants, they are changing as $(x,y)$ changes so what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $O = (0,0)$ be the center of the circle, and $\ell$ be the line $x = 0$.  Consider a point $P$ on the locus; by construction, $P$ is the center of a circle tangent to circle $O$ and line $\ell$, therefore $P$ is equidistant from the point of tangency $T$ to circle $O$ and line $\ell$.  That is to say, $PT = PR$, where $R$ is the foot of the perpendicular from $P$ to $\ell$.  But $O$ is collinear with $P$ and $T$, and $OT = 1$, a constant.  So this suggests that we construct two lines $\ell'$ and $\ell''$ parallel on either side of $\ell$ such that the distance between $\ell$ and $\ell'$ is $1$, and similarly, the distance between $\ell$ and $\ell''$ is $1$.  Then $\ell'$ and $O$ are the directrix and focus of a parabola which is one half of the desired locus of points, and $\ell''$ and $O$ are the directrix and focus of the other half of the locus.  Therefore, the complete locus is the union of two parabolas as described.

[image]

Comment: IS my approach correct? what am I missing ?

Comment: @Learner Your approach is incomplete, for the reason that there are additional constraints on $(a,b)$ in terms of the choice of $(x,y)$; namely, $ay = bx$, because the point of the circle's tangency with the unit circle is collinear with the centers of the two circles; and $a^2+b^2=1$ (as given in the other answer), because $(a,b)$ lies on the unit circle.  That said, the answer I provided should suggest to you a more elegant approach:  if you study the answer carefully, you should conclude that $1+|x| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, thus eliminate the need to introduce $(a,b)$ in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

$a^2+b^2=1$  . As they lie on the unit circle. So now you can replace them with $x,y$ to get a second degree equation which is the required locus.

Comment: I dont get it. I get the equation $2ax + 2by = y^2 +1 $... how can we use $a^2+ b^2 =1$ in this euqation?

Answer (score 0):

The locus of centers of the circle have the coordinates (x,y). Since this circle is tangent to the y axis, the radius of the circle will be the value of the x coordinate, (sketch on graph if you are unsure why). The circle x^2+y^2=1 has a radius of 1. Since the two circles are tangent to each other, then the distance between the centers of the circles are the sum of the different radii (x+1). The distance between the centers of the circles can also be denoted using distance formula. Thus the distance can also be written as the square root of: (x-0)^2+(y-0)^2, being that the center of the first circle is (0,0). You set the distance formula equal to the sum of the radii, and solve. The answer should be y^2 = 2x+1. This becomes the locus of the centers of circles tangent to the y-axis, and tangent to the unit circle.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).